# Flutter version 3.19.2 requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. /android/build.gradle: ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

Tags: flutter, kotlin, version

I have a question about Flutter version 3.19.2. In this version, Flutter has removed the buildscript from the `/android/build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
        
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now, I'm wondering where to put the latest version of Kotlin. Could someone please guide me on the appropriate location for specifying the Kotlin version in this updated configuration?

Thank you in advance!

I have attempted to search for information on the Flutter documentation website under [Breaking Changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes), but I couldn't find anything related to this particular issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kotlin plugin version is shifted to settings.gradle in newer version of flutter.
you can find kotlin plugin version in `settings.gradle` inside `plugins` tag

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "{agpVersion}" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "{kotlinVersion}" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After the update of Flutter version 3.19.2. In this version, Flutter has removed the buildscript from the

```
 /android/build.gradle
```

Now you can Add your latest version of Kotlin in settings.gradle

```
/android/setting.gradle
```

here is my setting.gradle file:

```
pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}
settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
}

plugins {
id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
id "com.android.application" version "8.1.2" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Documents they said,
In Flutter 3.16, support was added for applying these plugins with Gradle’s declarative plugins {} block (also called the Plugin DSL) and it is now the recommended approach. Since Flutter 3.16, projects generated with flutter create use the Plugin DSL to apply Gradle plugins. Projects created with versions of Flutter prior to 3.16 need to be migrated manually.

Applying Gradle plugins using the plugins {} block executes the same code as before and should produce equivalent app binaries.

`android/settings.gradle`
Replace the contents of /android/settings.gradle with the below, remembering to replace {agpVersion} and {kotlinVersion} with previously used values:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "{agpVersion}" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "{kotlinVersion}" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

If you made some changes to this file, make sure they’re placed after pluginManagement {} and plugins {} blocks, since Gradle enforces that no other code may be placed before these blocks.

`android/build.gradle`
Remove the whole buildscript block from <app-src/android/build.gradle:

```
-buildscript {
-    ext.kotlin_version = '{kotlinVersion}'
-    repositories {
-        google()
-        mavenCentral()
-    }
-
-    dependencies {
-        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
-    }
-}
```

Here’s how that file will likely end up:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle`

Most changes have to be made in the /android/app/build.gradle. First, remove these 2 chunks of code that use the legacy imperative apply method:

```
-if (flutterRoot == null) {
-    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
-}
```

```
-apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
-apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

Now apply the plugins again, but this time using the Plugin DSL syntax. At the very top of your file, add:

```
+plugins {
+    id "com.android.application"
+    id "kotlin-android"
+    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
+}
```

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

Answer (score 2):

I did the following steps - Worked for me

1. Change the Kotlin version to the latest version, in android/settings.gradle file

In my case, it was 1.9.0 :

```
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
```

2. Run --> `flutter clean`
3. get into the Android folder and run --> `./gradlew cleanBuildCache`
4. Go to %USERPROFILE%/.gradle and delete the --> caches folder.
5. Run the Flutter app using the play-icon button

NOTE: If the .gradle/caches dosent get deleted then

1. Press Windows + R and type -->  resmon
2. Under Associated Handles, search --> gradle
3. End the java.exe process with gradle/caches in its path.