Build Gradle Fail with exception after updating kotlin version
I updated my application to kotlin version 2.0.0 for a package but I am now getting this error when launching my flutter app.
Thus far tried to change gradle and java versions
Gradle version: 7.6.3
JVM Version: 19.0.1
running gradle build also brings up some errors
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

This was the output after updating my kotlin versions -
    Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
ERROR:C:\Users\Luis\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a675a47b7c37888d544b11bdfc0fd529\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.1-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:C:\Users\Luis\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\68f23b9903385e7deff280e9b08cb8be\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:C:\Users\Luis\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a3d9eea2ef2fe4db88b4de9d99e2fae1\transformed\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null

    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-resources-1.7.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=26, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Luis\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\68f23b9903385e7deff280e9b08cb8be\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.7.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=26, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Luis\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a3d9eea2ef2fe4db88b4de9d99e2fae1\transformed\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.8.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=26, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Luis\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a675a47b7c37888d544b11bdfc0fd529\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.1-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

Settings.Gradle File -
    pluginManagement {
        def flutterSdkPath = {
            def properties = new Properties()
            file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
            def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
            assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
            return flutterSdkPath
        }
        settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()
    
        includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")
    
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
    
    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
        id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false
        id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false // 1.7.21 works
    }
    
    include

 ":app"

android/app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}



android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_todo_app"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true // flutter local notification
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {

        multiDexEnabled true // flutter local notification
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_todo_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName



      

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    
   implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
   coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'

   



}


does this answers your question

You can get your Answer here please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78080244/flutter-version-3-19-2-requires-a-newer-version-of-the-kotlin-gradle-plugin-an

I updated my kotlin vresion but still having erros with launching

I've got the same issue after updating flutter dependencies. Only trying to use kotlin 1.9.24 too. Let me know if you solve.

The issue is due to mismatching compileSDKVersions, it has been fixed in the latest release (version 1.2.0) of the package.

Hey, thanks for the tip about updating to version 1.2.0. I'm a bit lost though - which package are you talking about? I looked through my files but couldn't find anything specific that matches up with that version.
