issue with kotlin, outdated and how to fix within gradle.build
I keep reading other accounts of this issue, how my version needs to be downgraded, but all the response say go to gradle.build, but mine does not match all the replies.
andriod/gradle.build
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

one said all i have to do is add(below) but where, i dont see my file match any of the ones ive seen answered here
ext.kotlin_version = ''
trying to resolve this issue to move forwards building, just recently appeared

does this answers your question

You can get your answer here please check it.
The ans is describe here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78080244/flutter-version-3-19-2-requires-a-newer-version-of-the-kotlin-gradle-plugin-an

if your project denpends on plugin dsl
you can change kotlin version in

seeting.gradle in android level



thank you, i made the changes and can continue.
thank you very much
